# Logging round trip to server with RestKit 2

Tags: afnetworking, restkit-0.20

I am trying to figure out how long my round trip to the server is before any mapping occurs. I need to get at the RKObjectRequestOperation, but it is only available in the success and fail blocks.

I see that RestKit 2 does send a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RKObjectRequestOperationDidStartNotification object:weakSelf];
```

But there is no user info sent along.

Any ideas on how I can do this? I was thinking of an associated object onto the operation queue but that is causing crashes.

What I did:

```
    self.op = self.objectManager.operationQueue.operations.lastObject;
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kRetrieverRequestOperationKey, self.op, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Added the above right after:

```
[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPath:resourcePath parameters:parmsDictionary success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {
     [weakSelf didLoadOperation:requestOperation result:mappingResult isFromCache:NO];
     [weakSelf requestDidEnd:requestOperation];

 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation, NSError *error) {

     [weakSelf requestOperation:requestOperation didFailWithError:error];
     [weakSelf requestDidEnd:requestOperation];

 }];
```

Then when RestKit posted its notification I was able to get at the RKObjectRequestOperation.
Not ideal, but seems to work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information that you need user info? If you do need it, can you fork RestKit and edit...

Comment: We originally forked RestKit 1 and it got us in trouble and made uplifting to RestKit2 a real pain.